# Nivo slider wrong positioned in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, nivo-slider

My nivoslider slideshow on my index page shows us correctly in chrome, IE 10 and opera.
Only in Firefox it shows us up on the right side.
Here is my site: http://www.colombian-emerald-jewelry.com/

How can I fix this ?

I appreciate your help

Comment: Try adding code next time and not just ask for an answer ...I edited it for you below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also just add `float:left;` to the `nivoSlider` `class`:

```
.nivoSlider {
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Positioning** is the way I got it working, in both browsers try this:

Add:

```
.slider-wrapper {
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Edit:

```
.theme-default .nivoSlider {
    background: url("loading.gif") no-repeat scroll 50% 50% #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 #D3D3D3;
    position: absolute;
}

.theme-default .nivo-controlNav {
    bottom: 0;
    clear: both;
    left: 45%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone meets the same problem, but wants to avoid using float (it forces using clearfix if your slider is let's say above the main content of page), the clear: both works even better.

```
.nivoSlider {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both
}
```